# Do I have to take an RMD from my IRA next year?

Tags: united-states, ira, rmd

I turned 70.5 last year and was required to take my required minimum distribution. I took it, but the laws changed at the end of last year making the new age for RMD  at 72.

Do I have to take the RMD this year when I turn 71?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jamiehopkins/2019/12/18/why-the-secure-act-makes-2020-the-year-of-missed-rmds-from-iras/): "For anyone who has not already reached age 70.5 by the end of 2019, the new required beginning date will be 72 for RMDs..."

"...So, if you turn 70.5 by the end of 2019, you will need to start taking RMDs for 2019. The first one needs to come out by April 1, 2020. However, if you turn 70.5 after Jan. 1, 2020, you now won’t be required to take an RMD for 2020. In fact, no one will be required to take a 2020 RMD based on turning 70.5 in 2020."

Comment: @JACK: You mean that you are grandfathered into the old rules, and thus the new (better) rules don't apply to you.

Comment: There's no such thing as "grandfathered to the new rules".  ["Grandfathered" means that rule changes don't affect you, you keep using the old rules.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/81197/3540)  You are grandfathered.